# Write to hidden link table directly

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In Entity Framework I have a table something like this:

`ActorId`
`Name`

and another like this:

`MovieId`
`Title`

And these are populated from an external file.

Then I have another external file which contains all the links. The `Actor` to `Movie` link is many-to-many. So this link file contains something like:

`ActorId`
`MovieId`

But in EF, the `ActorToMovie` table is hidden. So you can't directly write to it. So if I want to process the links, I would have to first find the matching entry in the `Movie` database and then find the matching entry in the `Actor` database and then link them with something like:

```
myMovie.Actors.Add(myActor);
```

But this is inefficient for a mass insert. Is there a better way (other than just raw SQL) to write directly to the `ActorToMovie` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another column (`ID`, `DateAdded`, etc...) to the `ActorToMovie` table so it shows up as an entity.

So your classes would look like

```
Actor
    int ActorId
    string Name
    List<ActorToMovie> Movies

Movie
    int MovieID
    string Title
    List<ActorToMovie> Actors

ActorToMovie
    int ID
    Movie Movie
    Actor Actor
    DateTime DateAdded
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit hacky, but it is a simple, quick solution.

Comment: you don't even need the extra property unless you generate the model classes db first, because then you can simply register this entity and use it like any other.